# Does anyone used rpc framework inside libevent?

Tags: rpc, libevent

I have a multiserver multiclient application and I would like to keep some common data managed by a single daemon (to avoid a nightmare f concurrency), so the servers can just ask it when they need to manipulate the shared data.

I am already using libevent in the servers so I would like to stick to it and use it's RPC framework but I could not find an example of it used in real world.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) provides a RPC framework. And it is also used inside Google for RPC and many other things.

Protobuf is a library for data exchanging. 
It handles data serialization, deserialization, compression, and so on.
It is created and opensourced by Google.
However, they didn't opensource the part of RPC implementation.
It only provides a framework.

You can integrate Protobuf with your existing libevent program.

I have personally implemented a RPC with Protobuf and libev(which is a similar project to libevent). And they work fine.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. I think OP asked `evrpc` which is part of libevent.